# What happened between March 28th and March 29th, 1976 with the java.util.GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, scala, date, long-integer, gregorian-calendar

Trying to use the GregorianCalendar, I got stuck on a singularity while computing the number of days since a particular date.
In the scala interpreter, I entered :

```
scala>import java.util.GregorianCalendar
scala>import java.util.Calendar
scala>val dateToday = new GregorianCalendar(2012,Calendar.MAY,22).getTimeInMillis()
dateToday: Long = 1337637600000
scala>val days1 = (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976,Calendar.MARCH,28).getTimeInMillis())) / (1000*3600*24)
days1: Long = 13203
scala>val days2 = (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976,Calendar.MARCH,29).getTimeInMillis())) / (1000*3600*24)
days2: Long = 13203
```

I don't know if the fact that 1976 is a leap year matters, but days1 and days2 should have been separated by 1. This is the only moment in history since 1970 that this singularity happens.

Wanting to know what is going on, I compute the difference between the two dates previously mentionned, and it gives me only exactly 23 hours of difference ! What happened on that date ? Wikipedia apparently says nothing about it.

And even more important, how to compute the real number of days since a particular date ?

Comment: You should make `dateToday` a `def`, otherwise the offset is getting weirder and weirder the longer one experiments with it.

Comment: for sure, don't worry, this was only to be sure that the date was correct for everybody. In the original code I wrote Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() instead.

Comment: I mean you should make it a `def` for *us* testers on SO. :)

Comment: Ok, I see, I should have renamed `dateToday` to `dateWhereIFoundTheBigDateBug`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the option of a float division is not available, the best answer I can think of is to add one hour (1000*3600) while computing a difference between two days:

```
scala> (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976, Calendar.MARCH, 28).getTimeInMillis()) + 1000*3600) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
days1: Long = 13204
scala> (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976, Calendar.MARCH, 29).getTimeInMillis()) + 1000*3600) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
days1: Long = 13203
```

It should work for every date, as you do not suffer from leap hours anymore.

Comment: Does `GregorianCalendar` deal with leap seconds?

Comment: Leap hours?  If you mean daylight savings time (the far more likely culprit), not all countries that practice DST do so at midnight.

Comment: @X-Zero Leap seconds. Every so many years, a second is added or removed to account for variations in Earth's orbit.

Comment: Yes, but `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` don't mention them, so I doubt that's the case.  `Date` mentions them, but seemingly as an aside, given that they point out that 'Most computer clocks are not accurate enough to be able to reflect the leap-second distinction.'  Use and implementation are therefore implementation specific (the example given in the documentation do not produce a leap second on my machine).

Comment: I seem to remember that in Java, the use (or not) of leap-seconds is implementation dependant.

Comment: [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10698470/642706) should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 46):

### The Problem

Daylight savings days are only 23 hours long.

And according to [this](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=195&year=1976) March 28th, 1976 was a daylight savings day in at least Paris.  The hour between 1am and 2am on that day simply did not exist.

Though it must be a Locale issue since on my computer I get it right:

```
scala> val days1 = (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976, Calendar.MARCH, 28).getTimeInMillis())) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
days1: Long = 13203

scala> val days2 = (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976, Calendar.MARCH, 29).getTimeInMillis())) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
days2: Long = 13202
```

I'm not in Paris or anywhere else that had a time change on that day; the time changed on April 25, 1976 where I am.  So I get the "skipped day" behavior on that date:

```
scala> val days3 = (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976, Calendar.APRIL, 25).getTimeInMillis())) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
days3: Long = 13175

scala> val days4 = (dateToday - (new GregorianCalendar(1976, Calendar.APRIL, 26).getTimeInMillis())) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
days4: Long = 13175
```

Erwin points on in the comments that the likely reason your only noticing the incorrect date difference here is that all of the other daylight savings days are offset by the 25-hour days that also happen in those years, when the daylight savings day is corrected.

### The Solution

Use a better library for date processing.  The [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library does it correctly (as well as being a better date/time framework overall):

```
import org.joda.time.Days
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants
import org.joda.time.DateMidnight

val d1 = new DateMidnight(1976, DateTimeConstants.APRIL, 25)
val d2 = new DateMidnight(1976, DateTimeConstants.APRIL, 26)
val x = Days.daysBetween(d1, d2).getDays()
println(x) // 1
```

Comment: Well, but why only on this date ? There were so many daylight saving days since. And how to get around this problem to compute the number of days since ?

Comment: Maybe the other 1 hour missing or added on all the other dates were offset (1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 = 1)

Comment: @meak: This should happen as well *after* this date. It was however the very first day the daylight savings time was (re-)introduced in France, so it should not happen *before* that.

Answer (score 3):

dhg pointed out what I think: This day is a "daylight saving time" day.
As this day is only 23h long, euclidian division by a day equals 0.

In fact, using GregorianCalendar objects is only using a date as milliseconds, so dividing by one day as an integer does only truncate a result.

Instead of an euclidian (integer) division, try to do a float division, then round the result.