# Calcul difference between two date for march month

Tags: java, date

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two dates.

*First case :*

```
    String string = "01/03/2014";
    Date dateFin = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE).parse(string);
    string = "31/03/2014";
    Date dateDebut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE).parse(string);


    long result = Math.abs(dateFin.getTime() - dateDebut.getTime());


    System.out.println((int) (result / (long) (1000 * 3600 * 24)));
```

=> Result :

```
   29
```

*Second case :*

```
    String string = "01/03/2013";
    Date dateFin = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE).parse(string);
    string = "31/03/2013";
    Date dateDebut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRANCE).parse(string);


    long result = Math.abs(dateFin.getTime() - dateDebut.getTime());


    System.out.println((int) (result / (long) (1000 * 3600 * 24)));
```

=> Result :

```
   30
```

**Question:**

Why there is a difference between this two cases?

Thanks

Comment: no the date is different

Comment: The date is different @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: They both print 29 for me.

Comment: I get 29 from both code examples.

Comment: [Perhaps consider upgrading](http://ideone.com/pBV9Sw).

Comment: I am also using JDK 6.

Comment: Please try the same test with 01/05/2014 to 31/05/2014

Comment: You try this: `System.out.println(((result * 1.0) / (1000L * 3600L * 24L)));` And you will understand what the problem is.

Comment: Daylight Savings Time is throwing off your calculation. `Date` is not the ideal class for performing this calculation.

Comment: what do you suggest? thanks

Comment: Instead of java.util.Date, use either the Joda-Time library or the new java.time package built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened between March 28th and March 29th, 1976 with the java.util.GregorianCalendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698470/what-happened-between-march-28th-and-march-29th-1976-with-the-java-util-gregori)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in `result` is one hour less than the exact `24*30` hours. If you add `3600000` (that is 1 hour) to `result`, you will get the exact `24` hours (expressed in milliseconds). Apparently in France they change clocks from Winter to Summer time in the month of March. So in March there are `24*30 - 1` hours, not `24` hours. This explains why you don't have the same problem when you try the two May dates. This is my best explanation based on what I'm seeing.

See also:

http://timeanddate.com/time/change/france/paris?year=2013
http://timeanddate.com/time/change/france/paris?year=2014

You are parsing 31/03/2013 (i.e. 00:00 AM). The clock change didn't happen
until 31/03/2013, 02:00 AM. So in 2013 you have the exact 30*24 hours in March,
while in 2014 you have 1 hour less as the change happened on 3/30/2014.

Comment: so why for year 2013 it ok but not for year 2014?

Comment: Well, since both the cases are in March, the daylight saving should be equal in both years, no?

Comment: @Narmer Are you sure in both years the change happened in March? Check these two and think some more. http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/france/paris?year=2013 http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/france/paris?year=2014 You will see why the result differs.

Comment: Nope, that's what I'm searching... Usually (at least in Italy) we tend to apply the daylight saving always in the same month and on sunday, to ease the change.

Comment: @Narmer He's parsing 31/03/2013. The change didn't happen until 31/03/2013, 02:00 AM. So in 2013 he has the exact 30*24 hours, while in 2014 he has 1 hour less as the change happened on 3/30/2014.

Comment: Right, just a matter of hours :)